# Form in Access 2007 Database missing labels and fields

Tags: ms-access

I have inherited a shoddy Access database that I just need to keep limping along until it gets replaced so I don't know so much about it. There is a form in Access that pulls from an external database that displays some values from a row. It worked fine until last Friday when it just stopped showing some of the fields. Not that they're empty, but that they aren't there at all.

Design View correctly shows the fields
[image: Design View correctly shows the fields]
Form View doesn't show several fields
[image: Form View doesn't show several fields]

I've tested the ODBC connections as well as the Linked Table connections and they all work so I don't think it is failing because it can't reach the data source. Also all the fields are set as visible.
Any help would be greatly appreciated in how to get the form looking correct.

Comment: Initially, thought there is code possibly in form Load or Open or Current event that sets visibility of controls. But if this never happened before, then something has changed. What is form RecordSource - is it a query joining tables? Edit question to show. If there is no code to analyze, quite possibly this is a design issue and question is not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Control.Visible = True in properties?